# Is Commenting from Command line possible for someone else's commits? (Bitbucket/Git)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am aware that we can add message to a commit by git commit -m ....

In bitbucket, we Suppose someone else has committed a change in a branch. Can I add review comments to the commit id from the command line? ( I am sure this is possible from the UI when we click on that commit id)

If yes, can we also send the comment as a file?

Comment: Review comments are a Bitbucket thing, not a Git thing. You would have to use a command-line Bitbucket client.

Comment: Changed the question to bitbucket. Thanks, But I am running them in a build pipeline, so when certain checker produces an output, I want to add them in comments. Not sure if i can add bitbucket-cli on CircleCI

Comment: If review comments are implemented via git-notes, like how Gerrit does, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes

Comment: *"Not sure if i can add bitbucket-cli on CircleCI"* You can, should work like anything else.

Comment: @Ryan Could you please explain how?

Comment: @Viv: Install it like your other dependencies and run it like your other tasks.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/zhemao/bitbucket-cli are you talking about this? It doesnt have comment feature.